# Sync objects between different Threads in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a non-stable test where after the `wait`-expectation I can get either 1 or 0 results. How to force refreshing the database? Or what is a problem with a thread syncing?

```swift
func testFoo() {
    let realmConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(inMemoryIdentifier: UUID().uuidString)
    let realm = {
        return try! Realm(configuration: realmConfiguration)
    }
    let expectation = self.expectation(description: "expectation")
    let dispatch = DispatchQueue(label: "queue")

    dispatch.async {
        let event = EventObject()
        try realm().write {
            realm().add(event)
        }
        expectation.fulfill()
    }

    wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 2.0)

    let objects = realm().objects(EventObject.self)
    XCTAssertEqual(objects.count, 1)
}
```

Comment: Is 2 seconds a long enough timeout? What if you increase it? Also, your `try` block has no `catch`. Is it possible that it's throwing an arrow when trying to write?

Comment: Yep, 2 seconds is enough, and write block executes without any errors

Comment: Not really sure what the question is - are you getting an error somewhere? Also a question; why this `realm()` instead of just `realm` as shown in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/open-a-realm/#open-a-local--non-synced--realm) - is that part of the question? And why not simplify with `let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)`? What's the purpose of a second delay? Why not 1s or 100s? Can you clarify what's being asked? Lastly, *Live objects, collections, and realm instances are thread-confined: that is, they are only valid on the thread on which they were created*

Comment: @Jay For working from different thread needs different instances of Realm object, for that, I created a block (or calculated property, whatever). Where's a second delay? There's just one wait function with 2 seconds timeout. My problem is that after the wait expectation I sometimes get zero results rather than one...

Comment: If you need different instances of realm object, you would need to create a copy of that object as Realm objects are thread confined. See [Copy Objects Between Realms](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-legacy/docs/swift/latest/index.html#current-limitations) or you can use [Frozen Objects](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/threading/#frozen-objects). See [Threading](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/threading/#threading) for some additional tips including opening a Realm on different threads.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create Realm object inside autoreleasepool

```swift
dispatch.async {
    autoreleasepool {
        let event = EventObject()
        try realm().write {
            realm().add(event)
        }
    }
    expectation.fulfill()
}
```

> You must remember to wrap everything in an autoreleasepool so the objects do not linger on the background thread.